# Rack Routing - NoMethodError

Tags: ruby, routes, rack

I'm trying to set up a basic routing system in Rack, however.. I can't understand why the first route ('/') works, and the second ('/help') doesn't. What gets returned in the case of '/help' is a NoMethodError. Why is that, and how can I fix it? Thank you.

```
require 'rack'

class MyApp
  def self.call(env)
    new.call(env)
  end

  def self.get(path, &block)
    @@routes ||= {}
    @@routes[path] = block
  end

  def call(env)
    dup.call!(env)
  end

  def call!(env)
    @req = Rack::Request.new(env)
    @res = Rack::Response.new
    @res.write route(@req.path)
    @res.finish
  end

  def route(path)
    if @@routes[path]
      @@routes[path].call
    else
      'Not Found'
    end
  end

  def to_do(arg)
    arg
  end
end

MyApp.get '/' do
  'index'
end

MyApp.get '/help' do
  to_do 'help'
end

run MyApp
```

Comment: to_do method is instance method but /help uses it as a class method. Modify this method to def self.to_do, it should help.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I get this error: Puma caught this error: undefined method `to_do' for #<Rack::Builder:0x00000000fde710 @run=MyApp, @map=nil, @use=[]>. How can I make it work.. in both a class and instance method way?